# Unable to save strings with html tags in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I'm having an error when saving a string with html tags. I'm saving it in a Text type field. I have a centos 7 server and using codeigniter 4. It's working on my windows with xampp though.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to save:

```
$data = [
    'Status' => 'On Process',
    'Remarks' =>
    '<p>Thank you for informing us.</p>
    <b>Test Header:</b> 
    <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    </ul>'
];
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
I/flutter ( 7933): <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught CodeIgniter\Format\Exceptions\FormatException: Failed to parse json string, error: &quot;Type is not supported&quot;. in /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Format/JSONFormatter.php:42
I/flutter ( 7933): Stack trace:
I/flutter ( 7933): #0 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Format/JSONFormatter.php(42): CodeIgniter\Format\Exceptions\FormatException::forInvalidJSON('Type is not sup...')
I/flutter ( 7933): #1 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/API/ResponseTrait.php(407): CodeIgniter\Format\JSONFormatter-&gt;format(Array)
I/flutter ( 7933): #2 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/API/ResponseTrait.php(114): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions-&gt;format(Array)
I/flutter ( 7933): #3 /var/www/html/api.myapp/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Debug/Exceptions.php(141): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions-&gt;respond(Array, 500)
I/flutter ( 7933): #4 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions-&gt;exceptionHandler(Object(ErrorException))
I/flutter ( 7933): #5 {main}
I/flutter ( 7933):   thrown in <b>/var/w
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'saving'? Because it looks like at some point you're running that through a JSON parser and it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @parttimeturtle sorry for the late reply. Its saving to the database. When I try to catch the error, it turns out its not the saving of string with html tags but an index error in my array. I'm trying to check for the value of an array with a not defined key. The error above makes me think that it has to do with the html tags.